# How can Java forward my windows credentials to a web service?

Tags: java, windows, asp.net-web-api, kerberos, credentials

I wish to access a web service from Java.  When I go to that web service from IE, IE prompts for my PIN, reads my credentials from my piv card and I see the proper results.  I'd like to do this with Java instead of IE.

I believe windows takes care of dealing with the credentials from my piv card (and is probably even the entity that is prompting for a PIN), so I think I just need to know how to tell Java it should forward my currently logged on windows credentials the same way IE does.

Comment: I believe that both .Net and Java support PKCS#11, but I don't believe Java can use the .Net library! Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html

Comment: Oops, it looks like I was partially wrong -- https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Using-smart-cards-with-Java-SE claims that originally Java used JNI to access the Windows API, but now has a pure-Java "SmartCard IO" library http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html